# Python Tuple: Int to Str

Tags: python, string, integer, tuples

I have a tuple that contains items in a key value pair. For example:

```
key               | value
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
"Flavor"          | "chocolate"
"chocolate chips" | 6
```

This list goes on and contains many key value pairs that are either string or integers. I want to turn all of the values into strings but haven't had any luck.

Using `str(value)` doesn't fix my issue.

Any advice on how I can turn all of my values that are integers into strings?

Comment: Your given code does not seem like a tuple at all. What does the whole of your tuple look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the question a bit to make it more clear and remove a typo. Please add the code you're using (don't worry, it's nothing we haven't seen before :D). Using `str()` on the value definitely works, so your error is probably somewhere else, but without the code it's anybody's guess. Good luck!

Comment: Is it a tuple or a dictionary?